# How to list all objects on a sheet, the caption and the value

Tags: vba, excel

I found this code in another post and tried modifying it but it bugs out.  The goal is to list all checkboxes and optionbuttons from a specific sheet, their captions, values and colors. (The .caption, .value and .backcolor cause runtime error 438. Also, I'd like to list them on a worksheet that is part of the same workbook, not a separate file as this code does. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Sub ListAllObjects()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFil As Object
Dim Sh As Shape
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\temp\summary.csv")

objFile.writeline "Sheet, Object Type, Object name, Object Caption, Object Value, Object Color"

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets 'keeing this in case I want it later

If ws.Name = "Hotel Check Sheet" Then

For Each Sh In ws.Shapes
    If InStr(Sh.Name, "checkbox") > 0 Or InStr(Sh.Name, "optionbutton") > 0 Then
    objFile.writeline ws.Name & "," & TypeName(Sh) & "," & Sh.Name & "," & Sh.Caption & "," & Sh.Value & "," & Sh.Color
    End If
Next

End If
Next

objFile.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get an "Object doesn't support this property or method" error is simply because a `Shape` doesn't have a `Caption`, `Value`, or `Color` property. It's basically just a container for the control, which you'll find at `.OLEFormat.Object`:

```
With Sh.OLEFormat.Object
    objFile.WriteLine ws.Name & "," & _
                      TypeName(Sh.OLEFormat.Object) & "," & _
                      .Name & "," & _
                      .Caption & "," & _
                      .Value & "," & _
                      .Interior.Color
End With
```

Note that neither an OptionButton or CheckBox has a `.Color` property either. You'll have to check the `.Interior.Color`.

Comment: Thank you, @Comintern. Would you please let me know how to use that in context? I tried putting it after "If InStr(Sh.Name, "checkbox") > 0 Or InStr(Sh.Name, "optionbutton") > 0 Then" but no go. Also, any insight how to write it to a sheet in the existing workbook instead of a new file?

Comment: @JoePatrick - Try changing the `If` statement to `If TypeName(Sh.OLEFormat.Object) = "CheckBox" Or TypeName(Sh.OLEFormat.Object) = "OptionButton" Then`